# exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AnnotationView setCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

This error only seem in Xcode **Version 5.0**

Before i created this my app in Xcode **Version 4.6.2**, it was working very well for me, but i got this error in Xcode **Version 5.0**

I created custom Annotation class for generate my updated location and address.

My Code Is :

**AnnotationView.h**

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface AnnotationView : MKPlacemark

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *subtitle;

@end
```

**AnnotationView.m**

```
#import "AnnotationView.h"

@implementation AnnotationView

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate addressDictionary:(NSDictionary *)addressDictionary
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:addressDictionary]))
    {
        self.coordinate = coordinate;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Above is my custom class. I used it in my MapView.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate ;
    theCoordinate.latitude = [self.latitude doubleValue];
    theCoordinate.longitude = [self.longitude doubleValue];

    AnnotationView *annotation = [[AnnotationView alloc] initWithCoordinate:theCoordinate addressDictionary:nil] ;    
    annotation.title = self.businessName;
    annotation.subtitle = self.businessAddress;
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(theCoordinate, 8000, 8000)];
    [self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
```

Please suggest me where i make mistake.

Comment: Just curious: Why have you made AnnotationView a subclass of `MKPlacemark`?  Why not make it simply `NSObject<MKAnnotation>`?  Also, "AnnotationView" is not really a good name since it's not a "view" but a model object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The superclass of your `AnnotationView`, which is `MKPlacemark`, already stores the `coordinate` - note that you pass it into the `super initWithCoordinate:` method - so you don't need to store the `coordinate` in your subclass. Let the superclass handle it.

In other words, you should remove this line from your `AnnotationView` class:

```
self.coordinate = coordinate;
```

If you need to access the `coordinate` property from your `AnnotationView`, just use `[super coordinate]`.

Be careful about overriding the properties of superclasses with your own property with the same name - generally speaking, you don't want to do this!

**As for why you are getting problems in Xcode 5 when it was ok before:** this could be because a different version of the compiler is interpreting the code slightly differently. Your code was always problematic, it's just that the compiler is now noticing a problem with it.

Comment: Sorry , sir i can not get you,, please can you elaborate your answer and also what i need to change with my custom Annotation class,, and also why it only happened in only XCode 5 not in lower version ?? Thanks Sir ,,

Comment: i did it as you suggestion but error was occur...Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AnnotationView setTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Then you've got a different issue now. Think about what could be going wrong. Does AnnotationView have a title property? Think about it!

Comment: If I've answered your question to your satisfaction, please consider accepting my answer. Cheers!